# Get the id from listview when an item is clicked

Tags: android, listview

I have a column in the database `_id` I would like to get this id when an list view item is clicked. Currently the code below is giving me the `position` of the item. I' am still playing around with it I have a feeling something is wrong in the method 'getItemId'

**onCreate method**

```
        ArrayList<String> arrayCatNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY name ASC";
        Cursor results = myDB.rawQuery(query, null);
        while(results.moveToNext()){
            String catName = results.getString(results.getColumnIndex("name"));
            arrayCatNames.add(catName);
        }
        String[] catNamesArr = new String[arrayCatNames.size()];
        catNamesArr = arrayCatNames.toArray(catNamesArr);
        lvActivityCategory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvActivityCategory);
        lvActivityCategory.setAdapter(new categoryCursorAdaptor(this, catNamesArr));
        lvActivityCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), categoryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("category_id", id);

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String s = Long.toString(position);
                CharSequence text = s;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

**categoryCursorAdaptor**

```
class categoryCursorAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public categoryCursorAdaptor(Context context, String[] data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.itemListCategory);
        text.setText(data[position]);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: all you need is to use `CursorAdapter` (for example `SimpleCursorAdapter`) - it provides correct IDs by itself, so the `id` parameter will be correct in `onItemClick` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> arrayCatNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> arrayIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY name ASC";
Cursor results = myDB.rawQuery(query, null);
while(results.moveToNext()){
            String catName = results.getString(results.getColumnIndex("name"));
            int Ids = results.getInt(results.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            arrayCatNames.add(catName);
            arrayIds.add(Ids);
}
```

Then in your onItemClick

```
yourCategoryId = arrayIds.get(position);
```

You need to declare your ArrayList arrayIds at the top, before your onCreate

Comment: Thanks again you are my hero on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You're welcome, but also note to search for similar questions, some of your questions might have been asked previously by another user. So you won't be flagged by moderators for asking duplicate questions.

Comment: all you need is to use `CursorAdapter` (for example `SimpleCursorAdapter`) - it provides correct IDs by itself, no need for any `arrayIds`

Comment: @pskink So what if a row is deleted from the database table?

Comment: nothing: you have an id to a non existing row, or you mean the row is deleted before making a query?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: also nothing: the adapter will provide IDs with "holes" for example if you delete the rows with id=0 and id=3, the adapter will provide IDs 1,2,4,5 for items on positions 0,1,2 and 3